# how to check if a different values are greater than different data frame rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame

```
df1   =data.frame(a=c(100,200,150,NA),
                 b=c(300,40,90,30),
                 c=c(12,500,1000,2))

df2 = data.frame(s= c(150,300,80,15))
```

I need to check whether the values of df1 are greater than df2$s wrt rows.
For ex. 150 will be compared to 1st row i.e. (100,300,12) of df will result in (F, T, F).
Similarly 300 to 2nd row and so on

**Required Output**

```
result_df =  data.frame(a=c(F,F,T,F),
                        b=c(T,F,T,T),
                        c=c(F,T,T,F))
```

it can be done in the loop, but is there any faster approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replicate to make the lengths same and do the comparison

```
df1 > df2[row(df1)] & !is.na(df1)
```

-output

```
      a     b     c
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or may also extract the column from 'df2' and directly do the comparison

```
df1 >df2$s & !is.na(df1)
```